# Why do i get a core dump error with my hash table when it exceeds a certain size?

Tags: hashtable, coredump

I implemented an `algorithm` that prints all positive integer solutions to equation `a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3` where **a,b,c,d are integers between 1 and 1000**.
To do so, I used a `hash table` to drop the `complexity` to `O(N2)`. `H = c^3 + d^3`

Below is the `hash table` that i used **(list of integer pairs)**:

```
int n = 10;
int m = pow(n,3)+pow(n,3);
list< pair<int,int> > hashTable[m+1]; //(*) Core Dump here if n>50. Why?
```

My code works correctly when **n<=50**. But I am unable to run my `algorithm` for **n>50**. So, I am unable to solve the problem for **n=1000**. I get a core dump in line (*). Can you explain why this is happening, and help me implement my `hash table` in a better way?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what language is this written in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you tried to allocate `hashTable` array on stack, which has size limitations (couple of megabytes by default). With n=50 and `sizeof(std::list<std::pair<int, int> >) = 16`, required memory size is only 2MB. Larger than that -- and you run out of stack size.

To fix it, allocate `hashTable` array dynamically or use `std::unordered_set` instead of implementing your own hash table.

Comment: When you use the method `push_back()`, I think we allocate the memory dynamically. I don't understand your answer. Can you please be more specific?

**Note: I replaced `list` by `vector` but it did not work either.

Comment: The list object itself is allocated on stack (it contains pointers to the first and last nodes), nodes are allocated in dynamic memory. There is enough stack for 250K such lists (n=50), but not enough for 2M lists (n=100). You need to create list objects also in dynamic memory, for example by replacing array with vector: `std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int> > > hashTable(m+1);`

Comment: Thank you. It worked with vector of vector of pairs. I can allocate a bigger size of memory, but there is a limit. I have `bad_aloc` if i try to create a vector of size 2*1000^3

Comment: Do you really have so much free memory? 2*1000^3 elements would require 32GB on x86_64.

Comment: I have 8GB of RAM.